# How to customize all response in .Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Im using .Net Core to write a json api server, so I need customize all response to like:

```cs
public class Result {
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public object Data { get; set; }
}
```

as

```json
{
    "code": 1,
    "message": "success",
    "data": ...
}
```

For some response(or exception), I can using `IResultFilter`(or `IExceptionFilter`) to format the response body:

```cs
public class ResultFilter : IResultFilter {
    public void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context) {
    }

    public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context) {
        context.Result = new JsonResult(new Result());
    }
}
```

But in some case(like `400`, `404` and `415`), it would not be enter the `Filter` and will return directily.

I was try to use [Middleware](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Middleware/Diagnostics/src/ExceptionHandler/ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.cs), but it could not hold them too.

So I want to catch all error and format it like `ExceptionFilter`, how can I do?

Answer (score 0):

`ExceptionFilter` can only handle server-side exceptions. Do you find that the case can't be enter the `Filter` are all `4xx` error, They are all client-side exceptions, So you can use `UseStatusCodePages` to handle these exceptions:

```
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseStatusCodePages(async statusCodeContext =>
{
    // using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;
    statusCodeContext.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

    switch (statusCodeContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode)
    {
        
            await statusCodeContext.HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync(
                JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result415)
        );
            
            break;
        case 404:
            var result = new Result {
                Code = 404,
                Message = "Not Found",
                Data = "......"
            };
            await statusCodeContext.HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync(
                JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result)
        ) ;
            break;
    }

});
//......
```

Comment: I try this, `404` will enter this method, but the other case were also never enter. Inspired for your code, I was tried to get `Response.StatusCode` in `ResultFilter`, and other `4xx` code can be catch(except `404`). So Can I get `404` code in `ResultFilter`?

Comment: Yes, I test it and find that `app.UseStatusCodePages()` can't catch the 415 error and `ResultFilter` can't catch the `404` error, This is a very strange phenomenon.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to solve 415 problem you can use this code:

```
services.AddControllers().ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions( options => {
       options.SuppressMapClientErrors = true;
});
```